# How to disable file indexing in Lubuntu 14.04?

Tags: lubuntu, hard-drive, indexing

I use Lubuntu on an old XP laptop, and it works like a charm. In XP I was able to turn off indexing of the hard disk and it would increase performance a bit and I found out how to do it Ubuntu as well but this does not seem to apply for Lubuntu. Is there anyone who knows how I can disable file indexing of the hard drive?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "and I found out how to do it Ubuntu as well but this does not seem to apply for Lubuntu" - it would help if you linked that tutorial here so that we can find the corresponding setting for Lubuntu.